# Finding the distribution of the number of transitions it takes to go from an initial state to an absorbing state

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I would like to apologize in advance, as I am *extremely* unfamiliar with the theory of Markov Chains, aside from the bare basics. So please bear with me. This is not homework.

I have a Markov Chain whose transition matrix is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3/4 & 1/4 \\
5/6 & & 1/6 \\
7/8 & & & 1/8 \\
9/10 & & & & 1/10 \\
11/12 & & & & & 1/12 \\
19/20 & & & & & & 1/20 \\
& & & & & & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
where you may assume all values that are not filled in have a transition probability of $0$.

The version above, note, is written so that the rows sum up to $1$. If you prefer the transposed version so that the columns sum up to $1$, it is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
3/4 & 5/6 & 7/8 & 9/10 & 11/12 & 19/20 &  \\
1/4 \\
& 1/6 \\
& & 1/8 \\
& & & 1/10 \\
& & & & 1/12 \\
& & & & & 1/20 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Suppose that one starts initially with state $1$, the top-left most state. I would like to find the distribution (more specifically, the probability mass function) of the number of transitions it takes to go from state $1$ to state $7$ (the bottom-right one). Obviously this is a random variable taking on values in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 6}$ with positive probability.

I believe, in Markov Chain jargon, what I am trying to do is find the distribution of the hitting times to state $7$ (what I believe is known as an "absorption state"), given an initial state of state $1$.

**Please note, though I would appreciate any complete solutions, I am not seeking a complete solution to this problem.** Rather, I'd like at least some sort of sketch so that I understand how much Markov Chain theory and mathematics I need to learn to solve this problem, as I don't have time to try to dig through an entire stochastic processes book.

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a smaller example, e.g., $\pmatrix{.5&.6&0\cr.5&0&0\cr0&.4&1\cr}$ where it may be easier to carry out the calculations, but where the main features of your example still prevail.

Comment: I known you wrote that you do not have time to dig through a stochastic processes book but I simply cannot pass this opportunity to recommend finding a copy of J. R. Norris’ markov chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any transition matrix $A$ the probability that if you start in state $i$ you will be in state $j$ in step $n$ (i.e., $p_{ijn}$) is given by $A^n$ (i.e., $p_{ijn}=A^n_{ij})$

For an absorbing state $k$, it is especially easy because it can only enter that state once so probabilities $p_{ikn}$ define a cumulative distribution function $(\lim_{n\to\infty} p_{ikn} = 1)$.

Therefore let $\alpha$ be the absorbing state, then the probability that the first hitting time $\tau$ is $n$ is given by $P(\tau=n)= A^n_{i\alpha}-A^{n-1}_{i\alpha}$

Comment: For anyone who needs to refer to this problem in the future, the transition matrix A used above should be that for which the *rows* sum to $1$, not the columns.

Comment: For a transition matrix whose rows sum to $1$, the state vector needs to be a row vector. However, I don't see any reason why a column state vector (and a transition matrix whose columns sum to $1$) is any less valid. I would hope that whichever convention is used would be explicitly stated.

Comment: In the column-stochastic convention you just have to interchange indices, so $p_{ijn}=A^n_{ji}$.

Answer (score 3):

Given the matrix and the two vectors
$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac34&\frac14&0&0&0&0&0\\
\frac56&0&\frac16&0&0&0&0\\
\frac78&0&0&\frac18&0&0&0\\
\frac9{10}&0&0&0&\frac1{10}&0&0\\
\frac{11}{12}&0&0&0&0&\frac1{12}&0\\
\frac{19}{20}&0&0&0&0&0&\frac1{20}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad u=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}^T
\quad v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\tag1
$$
The probability of hitting the absorbing state on step $k$ is
$$
u\left(M^k-M^{k-1}\right)v\tag2
$$
Using $(2)$, we can compute the cumulative probability of absorption:

[image]

Normally, we would sum the probabilities and get $1$ as follows
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty u(M-I)M^{k-1}v=u(M-I)(I-M)^{-1}v\tag3
$$
Unfortunately, $I-M$ is not invertible (the bottom row is all $0$). Thus, we cannot use $(3)$.

However, we can set the bottom row to all $0$, to get
$$
M_0=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac34&\frac14&0&0&0&0&0\\
\frac56&0&\frac16&0&0&0&0\\
\frac78&0&0&\frac18&0&0&0\\
\frac9{10}&0&0&0&\frac1{10}&0&0\\
\frac{11}{12}&0&0&0&0&\frac1{12}&0\\
\frac{19}{20}&0&0&0&0&0&\frac1{20}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag4
$$
Instead of totalling the contributions to the absorbing state, $M_0$ tosses the accumulation after each step. Then the number of people entering the absorbing state on step $k$ is
$$
u\,M_0^k\,v\tag5
$$
Now we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty u\,M_0^k\,v=u\,(I-M_0)^{-1}\,v=1\tag6
$$
as expected.

The expected number of steps to absorption is
$$
\begin{align}
\mu
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty u\,kM_0^k\,v\\
&=u\,M_0(I-M_0)^{-2}\,v\\[9pt]
&=597860\tag7
\end{align}
$$
The variance of the number of steps to absorption is
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma^2
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty u\,k^2M_0^k\,v-\mu^2\\
&=u\,M_0(M_0+1)(I-M_0)^{-3}-\mu^2\\[9pt]
&=714866906460-357436579600\\[9pt]
&=357430326860\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the standard deviation of the number of steps to absorption is
$$
\sigma=597854.7707094\tag9
$$